# When Using Typescript+angularjs the api result is not displaying in html

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Below are my controller and html: When my make api call in controller I am storing the result in result variable, Now,that result variable when I am trying to print in html it is not printing anything, I have used one more variable name in controller that is printing in html when I print it. But when I try to print the result variable in controller it is printing data in console. So, I am getting the data in variable correctly. But, why it is not printing in html. Please help.

**Controller :**

```
module typescript {

    var my_app = angular.module('my_app', []);
    export class test {

        public name: any;
        constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) {
            this.name = "Test data";
            this.getdata();
        }

        getdata() {
            return this.$http.get('facilities.json').success(function(response) {
                this.result = response;
                console.log(this.result);
            })
        }
    }
    test.$inject = ['$http'];
    myapp.controller("test", test);
}
```

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: <body ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="test as test1">
    <div>{{test1.result}}</div>
    <div> {{test1.name}}</div>
</div>
</body>

Comment: With Typescript you can use 'static $inject = [' $http'];' within your class instead of extending the class with it. Put it just above the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful with `this` semantics. In this code:

```
return this.$http.get('facilities.json').success(function(response) {
   this.result = response;
   console.log(this.result);
})
```

`this` is not referring to your `test` instance, but instead to whatever context the function is running in. Instead do this:

```
return this.$http.get('facilities.json').success(response => {
   this.result = response;
   console.log(this.result);
})
```

Now this points the `test` instance. [Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this) for more information about this new use of `this`. You still have to define the `result` property somewhere though :)

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @mrhobo. It worked :-) when i use arrow functions. But, Can you tell me how i can return the result property after the api call to the callee i.e something like , storeresult = this. getdata();. now storeresult variable should have api result.   Because, arrow functions will not support in IE8.Thanks in advance

Comment: Arrow functions are supported in ie 8 because typescript transpiles arrow functions to regular functions. Since your api call is async you require promises.

Comment: Thanks @ Lodewijk. I just want to get the api result and want to return the result. So how i can the pass the result to the callee after getting the response from api. With the above code if i pass return this.result it is returning nothing. can you help me ?.

Comment: @mahi244 `test.getdata()`is returning a promise that will resolve to the response from the API. You can't access that synchronously, only asynchronously. If you haven't encountered promises yet I highly recommend you read up on them separately and then come back to this problem. Once you do you should understand what's going on much more clearly.